# How can I get the core fields of Redmine as objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I'm currently trying to write a plugin for Redmine. In a page, I want to get all the fields (core & custom) that the project uses.

At the current time, I can get the custom fields as objects. So I have their names, values, types (date, text...) and other useful stuff.

I already get the core fields, I do it like this:

```ruby
<%
  array_trackers.each do |tracker|
      tracker.core_fields.each do |core_field|
          if !array_core_fields.include?(core_field) then 
              array_core_fields << core_field
          end
      end
  end
%>
```

So, I have all the trackers in `array_trackers`. I go through all of them to get their `core_fields` (like *Assigned To*, *Due Date*, *Estimated Time*...). But this function only returns strings, that are as follows:

```
["category_id", "fixed_version_id", "parent_issue_id", "start_date", "due_date", "estimated_hours", "done_ratio"]
```

I would like to get the core fields, just like the custom fields, as objects, so I could access their types. Is there a function to get core fields as an array of objects, or can I use the strings I already have to get them as such?

EDIT: I'm using [this doc](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/edavis10/redmine/index) to find any information I need, but I can't find any "CoreField" class or something. That's why I was wondering if there were any "special" way to get a core field as an object, that is planned by Redmine.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found how to get it information by single method, but separately it's available.

Standard attributes types:

```ruby
# hash with attributes ids and its types
object.class.attributes_builder.types
# hash with attributes ids and full info (type, nullable, default value etc)
object.class.columns_hash
```

Standard attributes values:

```ruby
# hash with attributes ids and its values
object.attributes
```

`object` in code samples is any Redmine object - `Project`, `Issue` or any other class instance

Comment: Thank you, but I can't find the class for the core fields. There is the CustomField class, but no CoreField class or equivalent. That's why I asked the question, but I didn't mentioned it, my bad.

Comment: Okay, I got what you meant. But I only get strings, values of those fields, when I want to get the field itself. I need a way to see what kind of format it is (date, int, etc...) without saying "this field is a date, this one is a string", etc... That would be too long and inneficient, IMHO.